# Apache minimum version for Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

Our current Apache installations are running Apache 2.0.  Now we'd like to add some Rails applications and plan to run them on Apache with Phusion Passenger.  I've gotten conflicting reports about whether we need to upgrade Apache to 2.2 in order to use Passenger (a consultant I highly respect recommended that; someone from Phusion says 2.0 should be fine.

Anybody running Passenger with Apache 2.0 in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one seems to have a definitive answer, I'm going to assume that the answer I was given by someone at Phusion is definitive.  It's on Google Groups at http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/789f4f6e8f1c542d.

He states that Apache 2.0 and up should be fine.  (As it worked out, we were able to go with Apache 2.2 for this server, so the point was moot for us.)

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that the minimum version for Apache with Passenger was 2.2, but if you head over to their site and look in the [Users Guide](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html) I'm sure it will say what you need.

Comment: I have read it very carefully, and it does not appear to state a minimum version.

Comment: I didn't realise that. You do need 2.2 to use mod_proxy which is how people were mostly connected to mongrel, maybe that's why I was under that impression.

Answer (score 0):

i was choose this way. (optional)

im havent using Pasenger when production, i get simple deploy rails now. only create rails app @ etc/rails_app/myapp/  and upload all app folder and public to myapp/app. then i just need to unchecklist @ environment for production and configurated at database.yml

then i copied public @ http/public_html folder

run mongrel -> rewrite 12007 to 80 -> restart mongrel

if u get problem, ur app only apper in index, and get error when link to another page.

only ask to admin host to configur .httaccess

for example like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myapp.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myapp.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ "http\:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1\:12007%{REQUEST_URI}" [P,QSA,L]
```

or do like railsninja said :)

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you suggesting that I use a single instance of mongrel instead of using Passenger?  Not an option for us -- this is an enterprise-class application and requires a robust deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* 2.2. 2.0 works fine and if it doesn't it's considered a bug. That said 2.2 is probably better than 2.0 so regardless of the minimum supported version you should go for 2.2.